# Where is the BaseX Db stored?

Tags: basex

I'm using BaseX to run an XQuery against a set of XML files. I set this up with BaseX by adding the XML files with the `ADD` command and then executing my XQuery command. This works fine on my win7 box.

I'd like to share this DB with others. I expected to find the corresponding files at the path of the BaseX DB, but this directory is empty.

What's the BaseX way of sharing this work with other developers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By calling `INFO` or `db:system()`, you will see where your database is stored. Some general information on the location of databases can be found in the documentation of BaseX (→ [Configuration](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Configuration)).

Answer (score 1):

I believe if you use the function db:name or db:path with the name of a known node, you can get the path to the database.

It may be in-memory however, so you can use the export function to make it persist on the file system.